# Print image files using python

Tags: python-3.x, printing, python-imaging-library, barcode, barcode-printing

I generated some barcode files using **python-barcode** as png image files.

and I would like to know the best way to actually print those image files on actual paper using the system printer.

Bulk processing is the way for me.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can use a pillow lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it works pywin32 , sample document link
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.